# multi computer map-reduce in C#

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, mapreduce, cluster-computing

Is there a simple Map-Reduce library or implementation for .NET that allows a task to start on one computer and be split amongst multiple worker computers, perhaps using WCF or something else bit more efficient to manage the inter machine communication?

I looked at Microsoft's Dryad but from the docs it seems it is more intended for long running parallel problems (e.g. simulation problems that run overnight on clusters of computers) rather than what I am looking for which is one that should execute and return results very quickly. i.e. I have a highly CPU bound task that needs many more cores than a single computer has available and it should take a second or so to complete, including sending data back and forth between the nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Qizmt](http://code.google.com/p/qizmt/)  Made by MySpace team. As far as i remember had some OS restrictions (i.e. server Windows or Vista+ - check out for details).